# which query is better to get DATE + 23:59:59

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, 23, DATEADD(mi,59 ,  DATEADD(ss,59 , '2019-09-22 00:00:00.000')))
SELECT DATEADD(dd,1, DATEADD(ss, -1 , '2019-09-22 00:00:00.000'))
```

result

> ```
> 2019-09-22 23:59:59.000
> 2019-09-22 23:59:59.000
> ```

both have same result but witch is better as performance

Comment: When I was much, much younger I used to spend days working on what was the most efficient way to do something. But the fact is, unless you are doing this a billion times, it is very, very unlikely to make one iota of a difference.

Comment: On the other hand it is much more important to make your expression as "readable" as possible (for us humans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is "better".  There can be multiple ways to express something in SQL.  For instance, here are some other ways:

```
select convert(datetime, '2020-09-22') + convert(datetime, '23:59:59')
select datetimefromparts(2020, 09, 22, 23, 59, 59, 0)
select convert(datetime, '2020-09-22' + ' 23:59:59')
```

For your particular examples, the first has three function calls and the second has two.  That would normally mean that the second is a wee, wee bit faster.  However, the compiler probably pre-calculates these anyway, so that doesn't make a difference.

More important is *why* you would want to do this.  I have see this type of calculation used to support `between` with datetime values:

```
where getdate() between startdt and enddt
```

If that is your intention, *fix your logic*.  It is much better to have the upper bound be non-inclusive, so you write:

```
where getdate() >= startdt and getdate < enddt
```

Then the you can use '2019-06-23' for the end date, not worry about "getting the last second", and not having a bug where you miss the last second of every day.

Aaron Bertrand has an extensive discussion on the use of `between` with date/time values:  [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: My orginal date type is DATETIME

Comment: @AkbarAsghari, I suggest the inclusive start and exclusive technique Gordon mentioned so that you don't miss rows with fractional seconds in the last second of a day (e.g. between '2019-09-22 23:59:59.003' and '2019-09-22 23:59:59.997').